# How to generate a PDF from a dynamic page using firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a vue.js project connected to Firebase. The app displays courses -> sections -> units. The client would like to print an entire section to PDF. Each section has X number of units.

For our example lets say the section has 8 units.

The code works on local but when live it only generates part of the content. In other words, using our example of 8 units let's say the total number of pages is 150. When on local it will generate the full PDF (150 pages) but live it might generate 30 pages or 50 pages.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

below is the code on Firebase.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    });
}

exports = module.exports = function (context) {
    const { admin } = context;

    return functions.runWith({
        timeoutSeconds: 120,
        memory: "4GB" //"2GB"
    }).https.onRequest(async (req, resp) => {

        if (req.method != "GET") {
            resp.status(400).send("Unauthorized");
            return;
        }

        let parts = req.params[0].split('/');
        let x = parts[0] === '' ? 1 : 0;
        let courseID = parts[x++];
        let sectionID = parts[x++];
        
        let url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX/sectionpdf";
        if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === 'true') {
            url = `http://localhost:8080/sectionpdf`;
        }

        url += `/${courseID}/${sectionID}`;
        url += `?uid=${req.query.uid}`
        url += `&uem=${req.query.uem}`
        url += `&cid=${req.query.cid}`

        if (!url) {
            return resp.send(`Invalid url: ${url}`);
        }

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ["--no-sandbox"],
            //headless: false
        });
        
        let page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
        await page.waitForSelector('div.section-pdf-container')
        await page.waitForSelector('#section-title')
        
        let element = await page.$('#section-title')
        let unitTitle = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, element)
        
        // wait for questions and answers to load
        await page.waitForSelector('div.content-has-loaded')
        
        const pdf = await page.pdf({
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            headerTemplate: '<style>html { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}</style><div style="font-size: 9px; color:rgba(0,0,0,.35); padding-left: 30px;">The Journey: ' + unitTitle + '</div>',
            footerTemplate: '<style>html { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}</style><div style="font-size: 9px; color:rgba(0,0,0,.35); padding-right: 30px; width:100%; text-align:right;">Page <span class="pageNumber"></span> of <span class="totalPages"></span></div>',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: { top: '0.5in', bottom: '0.5in', left: '0.3in', right: '0.3in' }
        });
        
        await browser.close();

        resp.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        resp.status(200).send(pdf);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we could replicate this issue? Perhaps you could share a sample HTML file for the webpage?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I can add the code that generates the PDF. Would that help?

Comment: Generates the pdf as in? The issue is related to Cloud Function and Puppeteer right or is it related to something else? If I try using puppeteer on a small website without any of these css selectors, it works fine for me. So it would be helpful if you could provide the page that you are trying to convert to PDF.

Comment: @Dharmaraj The generated HTML is 8866 lines. I am not sure how to provide this...

Comment: A [Gist](https://gist.github.com) should do. Also the `if (!url)` check if redundant as URL is always a string.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Does this work? https://gist.github.com/jsd219/cecddd69f245dfdec416155783b18c33